# Shopify website not loading an image on intial load

Tags: shopify

I'm helping a friends company do some updates on their website and there is one issue I can't seem to fix.

When I load try load a product detail page, on initial load the image doesn't show up until I refresh or click on the next image button.

They are using a TON of plugins and not sure if there is some conflict.

Can someone help me look at the code error message in Inspector to see why the image isn't loading that would be great

Website can be found [here](https://featherandbone.com.hk/products/new-zealand-ling-fish-fillet-200g-frozen)

Expected result:
Image loads on initial load

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Flickity` library doesn't not load the image on larger screen widths on page load. The library re-initializes when the browser is resized or if the user goes to the next image which causes the image to load and display on the screen.

In `application.js`, you can try adding `imagesLoaded: true` under the main-slider initializer and see if that fixes the issue.

Find this block of code in application.js

```js
// main slider
$('.main-slider').flickity({
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  imagesLoaded: true // add this
});
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, a quick fix would be to force a browser resize on page load.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
```